# Separação Silábica em palavras com final em ditongo ou hiato

Tags: divisão-silábica, ditongo, hiato

Estou ciente que, para não errar em acentuação gráfica, deve-se:

1. saber as três primeiras regras gerais de acentuação, assomadas das regras de exceção;
2. realizar a separação silábica;
3. exercer o bom senso.

Entrementes, mesmo tendo seguido essas sugestões, permanece-me uma dúvida pontual em relação ao item 2: separação silábica. Permita-me explicar a dúvida.

No caso da palavra *es-pé-ci-e*, proparoxítona, aplica-se a regra 1 de acentuação, "todas as proparoxítonas são acentuadas". Porém, num primeiro momento, separei essa palavra assim: *es-pé-cie*.

Noutra palavra, separei a palavra *equilíbrio* assim: *e-qui-lí-bri-o*, mas dessa forma está errado. Porque na última sílaba forma-se ditongo e, eu "hiatizei" a sílaba.

E se, por exemplo, eu estivesse agora numa prova, e tivesse que separar *Rondônia*, ficaria em dúvida. Porque num caso de separação, a última sílaba, pode ficar em ditongo, mas no outro, acontece hiato.

Qual é a regra de separação silábica que devo adotar e, aprender, para não errar mais nesses casos de separação silábica?

Answer (score 3):

Para mim a forma mais simples de acentuar as palavras é perceber onde recai o acento tonico se a palavra não levar acento. Então é:

- **palavras terminadas em *A, E, O; AS, ES, OS; AM, EM, OM; ANS, ENS, ONS* são graves, caso contrario são agudas**.

Agora há a questão da divisão silabica. Neste caso considero:

- Para efeitos de divisão silabica não se consideram ditongos crescentes.
- Sempre que há possibilidade de um ditongo decrescente, é considerado que há ditongo decrescente.

Ou seja, sempre que há uma vogal seguida de I ou U (que não seja igual à anterior), há um ditongo, caso contrario, não há ditongo.

---

Em relação aos exemplos que deste, não podes considerar ditongos crescentes.

Mesmo em relação à divisão silabica, apenas os ditongos crescentes com gu e qu são considerados. Ex.: á-gua. Mas para a acentuação, é tratado como se fosse um hiato, até porque sem acento corresponde ao verbo aguar, onde existe mesmo um hiato.

---

**tl;dr** independentemente da pronuncia, considera-se os ditongos crescentes como hiatos (duas silabas), a não ser que este seja com *gu* ou *qu*.

Answer (score 1):

No caso de equilíbrio - o final não pode ser separado, porque temos uma semivogal mais uma vogal - pois o "o" final tem som de "u".
O mesmo não ocorre com "espécie" e "Rondônia", pois ambos têm suas últimas sílabas formadas por duas vogais, logo não pode-se ter duas vogais na mesma sílaba, por isso deve haver a separação, como em farmácia, que é acentuada por ser proparoxítona.

Answer (score 0):

Farmácia: É uma palavra paroxítona terminada em ditongo crescente. A palavra farmácia tem 4 sílabas na regra da separação silábica, porém na regra de acentuação gráfica que considera que uma sílaba é composta opcionalmente por consoante e obrigatoriamente por uma vogal, a letra A deveria esta junto com uma consoante, por isso nao é uma proparoxítona e sim uma paroxítona terminada em ditongo crescente.